# What is the vocal range of an untrained tenor?

Tags: vocal-range

I have troubles below Ab2 and above Bb4 and above Gb5 in head voice / falsetto (I don’t know) I have a very light and thin voice usually I would dodge high notes but when I attempted one today I got the Bb4's (little hard but were clean) and Ab4's (easily also no troubles with G4vs and F4's. I can sing them during worst shape of my voice too) and cracked above that. What am I: untrained tenor or baritone? Also my G#2 is very dark growl like.

Comment: If you do get a concise answer, what will you do with it?

Comment: Will fix my weak high register

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't you do that anyway? Having a label on your voice won't help it. And there's a grey area at each end, anyway.

Comment: "Head voice" is a term normally used for female voices. "Falsetto" is for male ones. Better to just call it the M2 register to avoid confusion. Whether one is a tenor, or baritone, or whatever takes a lot of other factors into account besides just vocal range, and M2 and whistle (M3) registers don't really have anything to do with that. M0 (vocal fry) and M3 usually take a lot of training to get down properly. If you get a teacher, they will help you to not only properly define your vocal range, but also to expand it without damaging your vocal folds.